# how to get exitcode when launching java application from command line

Tags: java, command-line, exit-code

i made a program which returns an exitCode (from an ExitCodeGenerator).
it works very well when i launch my application with command line like :

***mvn spring-boot:run (i see my exitCode)***

but how to get returned exitCode when i launch my application with this kind of command ?

***java -jar target/<my-application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar>***

thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash:

```
echo $?
```

If you are on windows:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Give you the exit value of the last run program. For example 0 often for a successful execution, everything else for (different) errors

Comment: If I could help you, consider accepting it.